# Angular *NgIf With Semantic UI

Tags: angular, angular7, semantic-ui

Am Facing One issue with Semantic UI Dropdown with Angular *NgIf. When am Putting Semantic Dropdown Inside any NgIf condition. Semantic is not working. when i removed that Ngif Its working Fine. Any Solution for this.

WIth *NgIf,
Now Semantic Dropdown will not work. It will show Normal Dropdown.

```
<div *ngIf= "IsVisible">
<select class="ui selection dropdown"
   <option value="" selected="selected">Bedroom</option>
   <option *ngFor="let bedroom of bedrooms">
      {{bedroom.bhk_numbers}}
   </option>
</select>
</div>
```

If I removed *NgIf. It will Work Perfectly Semantic UI. Like this,

```
<div>
<select class="ui selection dropdown"
   <option value="" selected="selected">Bedroom</option>
   <option *ngFor="let bedroom of bedrooms">
      {{bedroom.bhk_numbers}}
   </option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put down the code you have tried to help us understand the issue better.

Comment: @shaktimaan I updated my Question. Please check it once please..

Comment: When you say it's not working, do you mean it isn't appearing at all? That space in the ngIf call might be causing issues, and I'd also check that the variable IsVisible is actually returning true

Comment: @AaronLavers I Mean Semantic UI dropdown not working. NgIf is working fine. When am using Ngif, That time instead of Semantic UI dropdown, Normal Dropdown is coming. Outside of NgIf Semantic is Working.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [hidden] instead of *ngIf. What may be happening is that because the element isn't in the DOM it's not being initialized. With [hidden] it will remain in the DOM yet not be visible.

```
<div [hidden]="!IsVisible">
<select class="ui selection dropdown"
   <option value="" selected="selected">Bedroom</option>
   <option *ngFor="let bedroom of bedrooms">
      {{bedroom.bhk_numbers}}
   </option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[hidden]** attribute to solve this issue. ***ngIf** will remove the subsequent inner lines of code from the dom. But on using **[hidden]**, it will stay inside the dom, but wont be visible to user.

Please replace

**`*ngIf= "IsVisible"`** with  **`[hidden]="!IsVisible"`**